# (My)SQL query with MAX and LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I´m using this query:

```
SELECT `servers`.*, `sponsorships`.`sponsorship_id`, MAX(`sponsorships`.`bid`) as maxbid
                    FROM `sponsorships`
                    LEFT JOIN `servers`
                        ON `sponsorships`.`server_id` = `servers`.`id`
                    WHERE `sponsorships`.`impressions` <= '1000'
                    GROUP BY `sponsorships`.`server_id`
                    ORDER BY maxbid DESC
                    LIMIT 3;
```

This gives me the following

```
    [1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 23
        [user_id] => 1
        [cache_time] => 1395557635
        [sponsorship_id] => 1
        [maxbid] => 20
    )
```

But the row with `sponsorship_id => 1` is not the one with the maxbid. What do I have to do to get the `sponsorship_id` from the maxbid?

**UPDATE #1**

I have these two tables:

**sponsorships**

[image]

**servers**

[image]

and I want this:

```
[1] => Array
(
    [id] => 23                       (servers.id)
    [user_id] => 1
    [cache_time] => 1395557635
    [sponsorship_id] => 3            (sponsorships.sponsorship_id) [see in the result from before I got sponsorship_id 1 and not 3 or 4 as it should be]
    [maxbid] => 20                   (MAX(`sponsorships`.`bid`))
)
```

So the problem with the current I have is that I get the max bid and get only one entry per server from the sponsorship table, which is what I want. But the problem I have is that the `maxbid` is from another row than the `sponsorship_id`. So how can I make sure that I get the `sponsorship_id` from the same row as `maxbid`?

Comment: You are grouping by `sponsorships.server_id` but you have different columns in `SELECT` statement, it is unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: @VladimirOselsky ok, I will update the question

Comment: for this kind of situation better to move group by in a seperate query in the join condition !!

Comment: ok, I updated the question, I hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: There are two rows in sponsorships that have the same (highest) bid value of 20 for server_id 23.  Is there criteria for choosing sponsorship_id=3 over sponsorship_id=4? The query in my answer will pull both; the query can be modified to pull only one of them, but it depends on how we are choosing one over the other, it that matters.

Comment: @spencer7593 if that is the problem it doesn´t matter which one, but I prefer the one with the lower sponsorship_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming from your *LIMIT 3* you want to find the top 3 servers with the highest bids. It might be better to have the servers table on the left of the join and use a double nested query to find the top bids for each servers and to get the id with the top bid from your sponsorship table.

```
SELECT `servers`.*, c.`sponsorship_id`, c.`maxbidNQ` as maxbid
                    FROM `servers`
                    RIGHT JOIN (select `server_id`,`sponsorship_id`, MAX(`bid`) as maxbidNQ from (select * from `sponsorships` WHERE `impressions` <= '1000' ORDER BY `bid` desc) d GROUP BY `server_id`) c
                        ON c.`server_id` = `servers`.`id`
                    ORDER BY maxbid DESC
                    LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: this would give back servers which don´t even have a row on sponsorhsips

Comment: @user2693017 That is true. A quick and dirty fix is probably to use a WHERE condition to filter out those without sponsorship, but this is inefficient and will take longer to process. Let me modify this to reverse the joins.

Answer (score 0):

To get the rows from `sponsorships` that have the highest `bid` for each `server_id`, the normal pattern is to do a JOIN operation to an inline view, something like this:

```
SELECT m.server_id
     , m.maxbid
     , o.*
  FROM ( SELECT p.server_id
              , MAX(p.bid) AS maxbid
           FROM sponsorships p
          WHERE p.impressions <= '1000'
          GROUP BY p.server_id
       ) m
  JOIN sponsorships o
    ON o.server_id = m.server_id
   AND o.bid = m.maxbid
   AND o.impressions <= '1000'
```

The inline view (aliased as `m`) returns distinct values of `server_id` along with the maximum `bid` value from all the rows that have that server_id. (i.e. max bid for each server_id)

With that set, we can look back into the sponsorships table, and fine the rows that match. Note that there's a potential to get more than one row back, if there is more than one row that have identical values for `(server_id,bid)`.

Those rows can then be joined to the servers table, pull the columns you want, and add any ORDER BY and LIMIT that you want, for example:

```
SELECT s.*
     , o.sponsorship_id
     , m.maxbid
  FROM ( SELECT p.server_id
              , MAX(p.bid) AS maxbid
           FROM sponsorships p
          WHERE p.impressions <= '1000'
          GROUP BY p.server_id
       ) m
  JOIN sponsorships o
    ON o.server_id = m.server_id
   AND o.bid = m.maxbid
   AND o.impressions <= '1000'
  LEFT
  JOIN servers s
    ON s.id = m.server_id
 ORDER BY m.maxbid DESC
 LIMIT 3
```

Comment: this works great, only the group by server_id doesn´t seem to work, as I get one server id multiple times. Any idea on how to solve this?